# how to release memory,object,viewcontroller when you pop to root ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, release, uistoryboardsegue

I am working with a navigation controller segue which contains around 5 ViewController. Each ViewController is preceded for another one like an installation app. The last ViewController contains a button which makes you go back to the first ViewController through this sentence:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My questions is, how can I release all the objects, ViewController, memory which I have been storing during the first execution of the application, and when I click the button to go back to the first ViewController, get the environment as a first execution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I have been storing during the first execution of the application"? Are you keeping a strong pointer to any of these controllers? When you popToRootViewController, all the other controllers should be deallocated if you don't keep a strong pointer to them.

Comment: Im not keeping anything as a strong pointer (only `nonatomic`). To clarify you, one example is, in one ViewController I have a compass which is using `LocationManager` object. This object remains active and upgrading, even when I call pop method...

Comment: How do you know that it's still active, if the controller it was used in is now deallocated?

Comment: Because I have a NSLog which shows me each second the values that LocationManager contains each upgrade

Comment: You'll have to explain that further. Where is this log? Is it in the root view controller? Did you create the location manager in one of the controllers that got popped off the stack?

Comment: My app structure has five UIViewController like that ->
UINavCon - UIVC 1 - UIVC 2 - UIVC 3 - UIVC 4 - UIVC 5
When you get the UIVC 5, the app finishes and by clicking a button it redirects you to the first UIVC (UIVC  1)
Exactly, in UIVC 3 I implemented a compass with a reference to `LocationManager`. What I am doing there is to initialise an upgrading method with `[locationManager startUpdatingHeading]` and inside of the callback method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading` I have set the NSLog

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. I've tried this, and as soon as I pop back to root, all the controllers except for root are deallocated, and my log messages stop. Try adding a dealloc method to UIVC2,3 and 4, and just put a log in them to log self. See if these get called when you pop back to root.

Comment: I cant use dealloc method because im using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)... could it be the reason of my problem?

Comment: You can use dealloc with ARC, you just don't usually need to, and you don't want to call super dealloc in it. This is not the reason for your problem

Comment: I did what you suggested me, and Its not calling this method when I pop back to root...

Comment: Ok, so you must have pointers to these controllers somewhere. What is the line of code you're using to pop back to root?

Comment: `-(IBAction)endApplication:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}` Im navigating for each controller by push segue...

Comment: Ok. That's fine. How are you going from VC1 to VC2? Do you do a push in code (if so what code), or are you just using segues set up in IB?

Comment: I set up all the segues in IB, but I didnt set up any segue in the last case (pop back) because Im doing it with that code

Comment: You're not doing any setup of controllers in the app delegate are you? I don't think I can help any more without seeing your code. There has to be references to these controllers somewhere, or they would get deallocated. I just have no idea where that would be.

Comment: I have set a couple of delegate controller to manage tables, LocationManager... Ok, thank you very much for your help. I will try to figure out any other solution

Comment: Ok. I'm guessing that these controllers are the ones holding pointers to the controllers that you're popping off the stack, so you'll need to nil those out somehow.

Comment: I have been debugging my app and I found out the elements which had been holding my controllers up. First element was a CMMotionManager and the other one was a NSTimer. Now, all my controllers are deallocated when I pop back. Cheers for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

This method pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller.

Comment: In my case, I am using a thread like this: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO] and after the method pop it's still working...any ideas why is it still working?

Comment: Even, I am using CLLocationManager reference which it is still working as well....so, I think that I need something extra to release that objects....